# Put a line above text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a line over some text.

This is what I want[image]

And this is what I got so far

[image]

this is the what I have in my application

```
<div class="zoekResultatLine">
    <h2 class="zoekResultat">ZOEKRESULTAAT</h2> 
</div>


.zoekResultatLine
{     
     text-decoration:overline;
     color : rgb(217, 217, 217);
}

.zoekResultat
{
    color : rgb(0, 158, 224);
}
```

Comment: `border-top: 1px solid color`?

Comment: You are copying text and layout of an official website but you cannot copy the HTML or CSS?

Comment: why not use a `<hr/>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give it a `border-top` and play with the `padding-top` to get it right:

```
.zoekResultatLine {
    border-top:1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217);
}
.zoekResultat {
    color : rgb(0, 158, 224);
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nq9Lzsq/)

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a workaround but you can make a div that functions as a line:

```
<div class="line"></div>

div.line
{
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can easily modify the line's width, height and colour, or even change the background to an image, add margins etc.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="zoekResultatLine">
     <h2 class="zoekResultat">ZOEKRESULTAAT</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.zoekResultatLine{     
    display: block;
}

.zoekResultat{
    color : rgb(0, 158, 224);
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/ndbyc7dp/

Comment: +1 for not being a lazy ass like myself and making a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can use a `<hr/>` element.

You can style these using CSS - see http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/